# React JS Modal opening from Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so basically I want to open Modal using button in my Navbar. When you're on main page you can see navbar in the top section then bellow is HeroSection....

This is my code:

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
import * as openModal from "./HeroSection";


function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);


  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);


  

  return (
    <>
      <nav className='navbar'>
        <div className='navbar-container'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            TRVL
            <i class='fab fa-typo3' />
          </Link>
          <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link
                to='/services'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Services
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link
                to='/products'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Products
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
                to='/products'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Products
              </Link>
            </li>


          
          </ul>
          <Button onClick={openModal} buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

HeroSection.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Modal } from './Modal';
import { GlobalStyle } from './globalStyles';

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
`;



function HeroSection() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
    <div className='hero-container'>
      <video src='/videos/video-1.mp4' autoPlay loop muted />
      <h1>ADVENTURE AWAITS</h1>
      <p>What are you waiting for?</p>
      <div className='hero-btns'>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
        >
          GET STARTED
        </Button>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--primary'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={openModal}
        >
          WATCH TRAILER <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal}/>
        <GlobalStyle />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Modal.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';
import '../App.css';

const Background = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const ModalContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #141414;
  p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  button {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    background: #141414;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
  }
`;

const CloseModalButton = styled(MdClose)`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
`;

export const Modal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  const modalRef = useRef();

  const animation = useSpring({
    config: {
      duration: 250
    },
    opacity: showModal ? 1 : 0,
    transform: showModal ? `translateY(0%)` : `translateY(-100%)`
  });

  const closeModal = e => {
    if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };

  const keyPress = useCallback(
    e => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape' && showModal) {
        setShowModal(false);
        console.log('I pressed');
      }
    },
    [setShowModal, showModal]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
      return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
    },
    [keyPress]
  );

  return (
    <>
      {showModal ? (
        <Background onClick={closeModal} ref={modalRef}>
          <animated.div style={animation}>
            <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
              <ModalContent>
        <img src={"./logo512.png"} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              </ModalContent>
              <CloseModalButton
                aria-label='Close modal'
                onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)}
              />
            </ModalWrapper>
          </animated.div>
        </Background>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

I tried to link the SIGN UP button in Navbar to execute "openModal" function in my HeroSection and hope that it will execute the code and open the Modal on the main page. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't call a component's function from another component like that. The way to do this on react is passing down the function `openModal` through `props` from a `parent component`.

For example:

Parent.js

```js
/**
 * Component that holds all three components
 */
function Parent() {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar openModal={openModal} />
      <HeroSection />
      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} close={closeModal} />
    </>
  )
}
```

So your Navbar can use the passed function

Navbar.js

```js
function Navbar({ openModal }) {
  ...

  return (
    <Button onClick={openModal} buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>
  )
}
```

And modal uses the state from parent to appear or not

Modal.js

```js
function Modal({ isOpen, close }) {
  return (
    <>
      { isOpen ? (
        <Background onClick={close} ref={modalRef}></Background>
        ...
      ) : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

I strongly suggest you to read the [official react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#rendering-a-modal-dialog-with-a-portal)

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the whole Modal.js code into App.js and edited Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
//*import { Modal } from '../App'; added this one


function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);


  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  /*const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev);
  }; and this one */ 
  

  return (
    <>
      <nav className='navbar'>
        <div className='navbar-container'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            TRVL
            <i class='fab fa-typo3' />
          </Link>
          <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link
                to='/services'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Services
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link
                to='/products'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Products
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
                to='/products'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Products
              </Link>
            </li>


          
          </ul>
          <Button onClick={openModal} buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal}/> /*also this one*/
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```